# Theme changing when data change AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a problem on amcharts.
On my page the user can change some filters, and the chart changes when a filter is changed (date, ..). At this moment I change the data of the chart, I remove all the series of my XYChart, and then I rebuild all the series.

But when I do that, I dont' know why but the theme I charged before I created the chart changes.
The only solution I've found is to dispose the chart and recreate it. But if possible I'd like to keep to same theme without recreate the chart but just the series and the data.

This is my update function.
The chart and its axes has been created and a theme has been applied.

```
   update: function (categories, data, granularity, symbol) {
        symbol = symbol || '';
        this._completeData(data, categories);
        var dateAxis = this.chart.xAxes.values[0];
        //Pour changement de granularité
        var baseInterval;
        var groupsInterval;
        var gridInterval;
        switch (granularity) {
            case "hour":
                baseInterval = { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 };
                groupsInterval = [
                    { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
                    { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 }
                ];
                break;
            case "month":
                baseInterval = { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 };
                groupsInterval = [
                    {
                        timeUnit: "month",
                        count: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        timeUnit: "year",
                        count: 1,
                    },
                ];
                break;
            case "year":
                baseInterval = { timeUnit: "year", count: 1 };
                groupsInterval = [
                    {
                        timeUnit: "year",
                        count: 1,
                    },
                ];
                break;
            default:
                baseInterval = { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 };
                groupsInterval = [
                    { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
                    {
                        timeUnit: "month",
                        count: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        timeUnit: "year",
                        count: 1,
                    },
                ];
                break;
        }
        dateAxis.baseInterval = baseInterval;
        dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll(groupsInterval);
        while (this.chart.series.values.length !== 0) {
            this.chart.series.removeIndex(0).dispose();
        }
        this.chart.data = data;
        this.chart.invalidateData();
        categories.forEach(function (category) {
            if (this.options.typeSeries == 'Line') {
                this._createLineSerie(category, granularity, symbol);
            }
            else {
                this._createColumnSerie(category, granularity, symbol);
            }
        }.bind(this));
```

To resume I use a theme, I create my chart. When there is a change I change the data and the series and I don't know why but the first theme I used is not kept.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem. All colors changing when I updated the data.

Comment: Finally I "saved" the colors of the series and I reapply them on the new created series